# Can I store data in SQlite database from Strings I've written inside the code?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-studio

I have an app that it stores data inside a database and shows them in a recyclerview. my recyclerview should contain images. I want the image URL's to be stored in the database. but I don't want to get the URL's from the user. I want to write the URL myself and inside the code and then insert them in the database. Is there a way to store data in database from inside the code and not from any edit text ?

Comment: What do you mean by 'write the URL myself'? So you going to hardcode the URL? Doesn't really make sense.

Comment: I want to write it as a string inside the code and then save it in the database. then I want to retrieve the string and use glide library to load the image in the recyclerview

Comment: Have you got the database functionality working? Are you saving any data so far or are you yet to implement that service? The reason I am asking is because whenever you are saving anything into a database, it has to be a string (or other formats) to begin with. For example: getting the string from edittext... edittext().getText().toString();

Comment: I don't want to get the string from an edit text from the user. I want to write the String (or multiple strings) inside the code and then insert them in the database. Is there any way to do it? or should I use other methods ?

Comment: That was an example of getting a string. Hardcoding a string is not recommended because if you've published your app and you need to change the string, you'll have to publish it again. But to answer your question, yes you can write/hardcode a string and save it to the DB

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know its called hardcoding the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure that I understood you right but if you need to write strings hardcoded in code just make any class with only this strings as constants and write them into database on every open of application. But this is bad practice. You can just use it from that class. Something like YourConstantsClass.yourConstant;

Comment: Thanks I'll try it that way. It's an app that I want to use it as a class project and I don't want to use it again. That's Why I wanted to hardcode the data.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote the code like this:

```
 public void insertwall(ModelWallpaper modelWallpaper) {
        ContentValues c = new ContentValues();
        c.put(Colwall_Url,modelWallpaper.getImageURL());


    try {
        this.getWritableDatabase().insert(TABLE_NAME, null, c);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

and in mainActivity:

```
wallpaperHelper = new WallpaperHelper(this) ;

    wallpaperHelper.open();


    ModelWallpaper modelWallpaper = new ModelWallpaper();
    modelWallpaper.setImageURL("https://tpc.googlesyndication.com/pagead/imgad?id=CICAgKDb4cfN9wEQARgBMgjiJeT4IZ5nOw");

    wallpaperHelper.insertwall(modelWallpaper);

    wallpaperHelper.close();
```